# Botón flotante IOS

Tags: ios

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para IOS, uso Swift, y necesito hacer un botón que esté en la parte inferior de la pantalla encima de un TableView(como el que tiene Wallapop para subir un nuevo producto).
No encuentro nada que me pueda ayudar a hacerlo, si alguien puede decirme alguna manera de hacerlo o pasarme algún tutorial estaré muy agradecido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En iOS no existe un "Floating Button" nativo, si te refieres al similar a Android puedes usar esta librería la cual yo he usado (funciona con Swift 2):

https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existen otras opciones como :

https://github.com/gizmoboy7/VCFloatingActionButton

https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGPlusButtonsView

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias :)